# Discussion of Example 2, section 7 on page 45 of Munkres’ Topology.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

In Example 2, section 7 on page 45 of Munkres’ Topology, the problem is stated as follows.

$$\mathbb{Z}_+\times\mathbb{Z}_+ \text{ is countably infinite.}$$

First, he defines a function $f:\mathbb{Z}_+\times\mathbb{Z}_+\rightarrow A$, where $A$ the subset of $\mathbb{Z}_+\times\mathbb{Z}_+$ consisting of pairs $(x,y)$ for which $y\le x$ by the equation
$$f\left(x,y\right)=(x+y-1,y),$$
and he defines a function $g:A\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_+$ by the formula $g\left(x,y\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(x-1\right)x+y$.

Then he leaves it to the reader to show that $f$ and $g$ are bijections.

Though there is a similar question, unfortunately, it isn’t in detail. So I have attempted a detail one.

The following is my attempt to proof of bijections.

Let $f\left(x,y\right)=\left(x^\prime,y^\prime\right)$. If $x=1$, then $f\left(1,y\right)=(y,y)$; hence $y^\prime=x^\prime$.
If $x>1$, then $x-1>0$ and $x+y-1>y$. So $y^\prime<x^\prime$.

Thus, $\forall\left(x,y\right),\ f\left(x,y\right)\in A$.

Let $f\left(x_1,\ y_1\right)=f(x_2,y_2)$.
Then $\left(x_1+y_1-1,y_1\right)=(x_2+y_2-1,y_2)$ implying that $y_1=y_2$; and hence $x_1=x_2$.
Thus, $f\left(x_1,\ y_1\right)=f\left(x_2,y_2\right)\Longrightarrow\left(x_1,y_1\right)=(x_2,y_2)$. So, $f$ is injective.

Let $x^\prime,y^\prime$ be given point in $A$. Since $y^\prime\le x^\prime$, there exists a positive integer $x \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ such that
$$ x^\prime+1=x+y^\prime, \text{ i.e.}, x^\prime=x+y^\prime-1.$$
Therefore, for every $(x^\prime,y^\prime)\in\ A$, there exists $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}_+\times\mathbb{Z}_+$ such that $f(x,y)=(x^\prime,y^\prime).$
Hence $f$ is surjective; and hence bijective.

Next consider the function $g:A\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_+$.
Since $A\subset\mathbb{Z}_+\times\mathbb{Z}_+$, it is clear that $\forall\left(x,y\right)\in A,\ g\left(x,y\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(x-1\right)x+y\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ for $2\ |\ (x-1)x$.

Suppose $\left(x_1,y_1\right)\neq\left(x_2,y_2\right)$. Clearly we have $y_1\le x_1,\ \ y_2\le x_2$.

If $x_1=x_2$, then  $y_1\neq y_2$ and vice-versa.

In these cases, $\frac{1}{2}\left(x_1-1\right)x_1+y_1\neq\frac{1}{2}\left(x_2-1\right)x_2+y_2$.
If $x_1=y_2$, then  $x_2>y_2=x_1>y_1$ and vice-versa.

In these cases, $\frac{1}{2}\left(x_1-1\right)x_1+y_1=\frac{1}{2}\left(y_2-1\right)y_2+y_1<\frac{1}{2}\left(x_2-1\right)x_2+y_2$ and vice-versa.

Hence, in either case, it is clear that $\left(x_1,y_1\right)\neq\left(x_2,y_2\right)\Longrightarrow g\left(x_1,y_1\right)\neq g(x_2,y_2)$.

That is,  $g\left(x_1,\ y_1\right)=g\left(x_2,y_2\right)\Longrightarrow\left(x_1,y_1\right)=\left(x_2,y_2\right)$.
Thus, g is injective.

Let $z$ be given point in $\mathbb{Z}_+$.
We can choose $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_+$  such that $2z \le (x+1)x$. Then, $2z \le (x+1)x \implies \left(x-1\right)x+2y \le (x+1)x \implies y\le x$.

Thus, we can choose $(x,y)\in A$ for which $y\le x$ such that $2z=\left(x-1\right)x+2y$.
Therefore, for every $z\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, there exists $\left(x,y\right)\in A$ for which $y\le x$  such that $g\left(x,y\right)=z.$

Hence $g$ is surjective; and hence bijective.
It follows that $g\circ f:\mathbb{Z}_+\times\mathbb{Z}_+\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_+$ is bijective. Hence $\mathbb{Z}_+\times\mathbb{Z}_+$ is countably infinite.∎

I wonder if my attempt is valid or not, if not, please suggest me.

Comment: In the final part where you show that $g$ is surjective, I think you need to prove that you can pick such an $(x,y)\in A$, or show how you demonstrate that those exist, with $y<x$.

Comment: Having said that the formula to construct $x$ and $y$ from $z$ is a bit annoying, it comes out to $$x=\lfloor\frac12\sqrt{8z+1}-\frac12\rfloor+1.$$

Comment: If $z=1$ take $x=y=1.$ Then, $g(1,1)=1.$  If $z\ge 2,$ then follow the procedure in my answer. This shows that $g$ is onto. You have already proved injectivity so you are done.

Comment: To show surjectivity of $f,$ you can be more explicit. Since $y'\leq x',$ then $y'<x'+1,$ and so $x'+1-y'$ is a positive integer. Call this positive integer $x,$ and you're good to proceed as you already did.

Comment: in principle, you need only check that $f\circ g= \text{id}_A$ and $g\circ f=\id_{\mathbb{Z}_+\times\mathbb{Z}_+}$

Answer (score 0):

For surjectivity of $g:$ if $z=1,$ then take $x=y=1.$ Otherwise, let $z\ge 2$ and choose an integer $k$ such that the triangular number $\frac{1}{2}k(k + 1)$ is the largest one less than $z.$ Let $m =z- \frac{1}{2}k(k + 1)$  and $n = k − m.$ Then, $m\ge 0, n=k-z +\frac{1}{2}k(k+1)\ge 0$ and  $\frac{1}{2}(m + n)(m + n + 1) + m=z.$ But this is just $g(m+n+1,m)$ since certainly $m\le m+n.$

Comment: But, when $z=1$, how would you choose $k$ such that $\frac{1}{2} k(k+1)$ to be less than $z$. In that case, it would be $z=k=1,\ n=1$ and $m=0$. It follows that $m\notin \mathbb{Z}_+$.

Comment: But, then, $x=2, y=1$ and $z=\frac{1}{2}x(x-1)+y=2$; so the original formula is violated.